# Scala forall example?

Tags: scala

I tried Google search and could not find a decent `forall` example. What does it do? Why does it take a boolean function?

Please point me to a reference (except the Scaladoc).

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html: `Tests whether a predicate holds for all elements of this list.`

Comment: maybe you got confused because you thought of the functionality of `foreach` instead (iterate through all elements)

Comment: Yes I was thinking its a parallel version of foreach.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The `forall` method takes a function `p` that returns a Boolean.  The semantics of `forall` says: return `true` if for every `x` in the collection, `p(x)` is true.

So:

```
List(1,2,3).forall(x => x < 3)
```

means: `true` if 1, 2, and 3 are less than 3, `false` otherwise.  In this case, it will evaluate to `false` since it is not the case all elements are less than 3: 3 is not less than 3.

There is a similar method `exists` that returns `true` if there is *at least one* element `x` in the collection such that `p(x)` is true.

So:

```
List(1,2,3).exists(x => x < 3)
```

means: `true` if *at least one of* 1, 2, and 3 is less than 3, `false` otherwise.  In this case, it will evaluate to `true` since it is the case some element is less than 3: e.g. 1 is less than 3.

Comment: so `forall(foo)` is equivalent to `foldLeft(true)((x,y)=> x & foo(y))`

Comment: @Jus12, yes, with the correction that it uses `&&` because it does short-circuit evaluation (it stops evaluating `foo` if it finds a `false`).

Answer (score 4):

A quick example of how you can play with this function using a `Scala` script.

create a `myScript.scala` file with

```
println(args.forall(p => (p.equals("a"))))
```

and call it with

```
scala myScript.scala a a a  // true
scala myScript.scala a b c  // false
```

Comment: why not use the REPL?

Answer (score 0):

Scala's `forall` is also a great tool to do something like applying logical **and** to a list of boolean values with the **early exist**:

```
val evalResults: List[Boolean] = List(evaluateFunc1(), evaluateFunc2(), evaluateFunc3(), evaluateFunc4(), evaluateFunc5())

evalResults.forall(result => result == true)
```

Comment: or `forall(result => result)`