# Short circuit Map Operation If Try Fails

Tags: scala, short-circuiting

I have a function like this:

```scala
def foo(item: Item) : Option[Int] = Try{
  // Some code that can blow up
}.toOption
```

I have a list of items and I want to map through them, and apply the above function. But if the function above blows up and returns a None then the result of the map should be an error:

```scala
items.map{
  item => foo(item)
}
```

Is map not the right thing to do here? It doesn't seem like it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called `traverse`. If you can use **cats**, it is as simple as:

```
import cats.implicits._

val result = items.traverse(foo) // Option[List[Int]]
```

If not, you can implement it pretty easily:

```
def traverse[A, B](data: List[A])(f: A => Option[B]): Option[List[B]] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[A], acc: List[B]): Option[List[B]] =
    remaining match {
      case a :: as => f(a) match {
        case Some(b) => loop(remaining = as, b :: acc)
        case None => None
      }

      case Nil => Some(acc.reverse)
    }

  loop(remaining = data, acc = List.empty)
}
```

Which you can use like:

```
val result = traverse(items)(foo) // Option[List[Int]]
```

*(however, I would suggest you to use **cats** instead, since it is more general)*.

Comment: So on the first failure this will return None overall?

Comment: @Mojo Yes, it will stop processing on the first `None` it finds. You can prove the handmade implementation does that, and that is what the **cats** version will do.

Comment: @Mojo For almost all _"small problems"_ I have had recently, there was a function in **cats** that do it in a very generic way. And when the function didn't exist, it was easy to create using the provided ones. That is the power of functional programming, I really recommend you to read about it.

Answer (score 3):

For out-of-the-box short-circuiting, consider wrapping the list-mapping with `Try` like so

```
def fooUnsafe(item: Item): Int = // might throw
Try(items.map(fooUnsafe))
```

If you wish to keep `def foo(item: Item) : Option[Int]` signature then the following will also short-circuit

```
Try(list.map(v => foo(v).get))
```

Comment: Problem is trivial and this is trivial solution to it.